# Why OnClick event of a button inside usercontrol not happening

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

.NET pros out there

I have a problem that i would like to share with you and if possible get an advice:

I am loading a usercontrol dynamically using datalist. i am loading this usercontrol for each row i get from the database, it could be 30 different instanses of this control.

when a user click the button, i want to be able to get the values of this specific usercontrol's properties, in my understanding, i heed the usercontrol ID to do that, thats why i want to assign my "custom id" to each loaded control so i will be able to find it later. 
maybe i am missing something, maybe this is not the best way, im open to suggestions.
anyway.....

UserControl code behind:

```
public partial class SearchBullet : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public static int i = 0;
private string casterLOGO;

public string CasterLOGO
{
    get { return casterLOGO; }
    set { casterLOGO = value; }
}
private string casterNameSB;

public string CasterNameSB
{
    get { return casterNameSB; }
    set { casterNameSB = value; }
}
private string player1NameSB;

public string Player1NameSB
{
    get { return player1NameSB; }
    set { player1NameSB = value; }
}
private string player2NameSB;

public string Player2NameSB
{
    get { return player2NameSB; }
    set { player2NameSB = value; }
}
private string mapSB;

public string MapSB
{
    get { return mapSB; }
    set { mapSB = value; }
}
private string gameFrameSB;

public string GameFrameSB
{
    get { return gameFrameSB; }
    set { gameFrameSB = value; }
}
private string serieSB;

public string SerieSB
{
    get { return serieSB; }
    set { serieSB = value; }
}
private string race1SB;

public string Race1SB
{
    get { return race1SB; }
    set { race1SB = value; }
}
private string race2SB;

public string Race2SB
{
    get { return race2SB; }
    set { race2SB = value; }
}
private string castURLSB;

public string CastURLSB
{
    get { return castURLSB; }
    set { castURLSB = value; }
}
private string likeAmountSB;

public string LikeAmountSB
{
    get { return likeAmountSB; }
    set { likeAmountSB = value; }
}
private string qRYstring;

public string QRYstring
{
    get { return qRYstring; }
    set { qRYstring = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        i++;
        this.PreRender += new EventHandler(Cast_PreRender);

        this.ID = "Result" + i.ToString();  


    }
    PlayButton.ID = i.ToString();

}

void Cast_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlayerName1.Text = Player1NameSB;
    PlayerName2.Text = Player2NameSB;
    CasterName.Text = CasterNameSB;
    ImageRace1.ImageUrl = Race1SB;
    ImageRace2.ImageUrl = Race2SB;
    Map.Text = MapSB;
    GameFrame.Text = GameFrameSB;
    LikeAmount.Text = LikeAmountSB;
    CasterLOGOIMG.ImageUrl = CasterLOGO;
    PlayButton.AlternateText = "yay";

}
protected void PlayButton_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    Image img = (Image)sender;
    string tt = img.AlternateText;
    int j = 0;
    Response.Redirect("default2.aspx");
   // lb.Text = img.ClientID;

}
```

}

The aspx page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="WatchLaterDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDSWatchLater" RepeatColumns="1">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <Search:Bullet runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="SearchResults" Player1NameSB='<%#Bind("Player_Name") %>'
                        Player2NameSB='<%#Bind("Expr1") %>' CasterNameSB='<%#Bind("Caster_Name") %>'
                        Race1SB='<%#Bind("Race_1") %>' Race2SB='<%#Bind("Race_2") %>' MapSB='<%# Bind("Map")%>'
                        GameFrameSB='<%#Bind("Game_Frame") %>' LikeAmountSB='<%#Bind("Like_Amount") %>'
                        CastURLSB='<%#Bind("Cast_URL") %>' CasterLOGO='<%#Bind ("Caster_LOGO") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <br />
                </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:DataList></div>
```

the problem is, after doing this, when i click the button nothing happens, i mean, when debugging, i never get inside the OnButton_Click event. if i delete the --> this.ID = "Result" + i.toString();  and the--> PlayButton.ID = i.ToString();  it's ok.

if there anything elese you might need to evaluate my problem, ill gladly prove and additional code needed.
 thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it Web User Control you are loading dynamically or a Custom Control? Can you post some code that shows how you are doing this?

Comment: Why exactly are you changing the IDs of these controls? I can see how it could cause a problem, but honestly I've never need to change an ID in codebehind.

Comment: What is the variable i in the load and the prerender ? It seems very doubtfull that its value will match between load and prerender. You may store your i once and for all in the viewstate of your control during load and not touch the ids.

Comment: hi all, thank you for your response, ill post below the relevant code, hope it will be enough....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution was like this:

instead of using an image buttom, i used Hyperlink.

on_Load event of the usercontrol, i assigned to the src Attribute of the hyperlink all the properties of my user control and passed those using

querystring to another page.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the itemcommand for the datalist.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx